# Need both background image and link text color in a table cell to change on mouse hover over the cell (with CSS)

Tags: css, hover

Sorry for a novice's question, but I am about to give up having spent whole day on this issue... I have searched this forum for a few hours, but still can't get the thing to work.

Would anyone assist me with CSS solution to the following problem please?

Basically, I have a table cell with an image background and a text link. I need the image and link color to change on mouse hover over this table cell at the same time. My cumbersome code looks about like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="160" height="36" align="center" valign="middle" class="menuitem1">
       <a href="http://www.samplesite.com">About us</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`
```

Then I tried all this in a CSS file:

```
.menuitem1 {
   border-right-width: 1px;
   border-right-style: solid;   
   border-right-color: #000;
   background-image: url("images/sample.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   padding-left: 17px;
}
.menuitem1 a:link{
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
}
.menuitem1 a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
}
.menuitem1:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url("images/sample2.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   color: #000;
}
.menuitem1 a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000;
}
.menuitem1 a:active{
   color: #000;
}
```

The problem is that the text link doesn't follow `block` attribute. So the the text color changes only when mouse is over it, not over the rest of the cell. Adding `width: 100%` to `.menuitem1 a` still leaves `17px` on the left (`padding-left`) that is not in the block. And it is even worse with the `height: 100%` has no effect and fixed height in px aligns the text vertically on top without possibility to change it.

Funny that if I don't have a hyperlink in the cell and have just text there, then this simple piece of code is sufficient for everything to work like a dream:

```
.menuitem1:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url("images/sample2.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   color: #000;
}
```

Isn't there a simple solution like that to the problem that occurs after adding a link?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What many beginning javascript programmers don't at first realize, is that *any* list of selectors can be strung together to new selector. So to change the background image, you are right in putting:

```
.menuitem1:hover {
    background-image: url("images/sample2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
```

But to select the `a` element, you should use the following format:

```
.menuitem1:hover a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jeremy, you are my life saver!!! Thank you ever sooooo much!!!! Works like magic!!! :)) Thank you once again!!!